# Angular HighCharts 3D , connectors not adjusting correct when alpha value is changed for 3d pie and donut charts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have enabled 3d for my pie chart and donut chart. When i change the **alpha** angle of the charts the connectors to labels starts distorting and they don't point to the right sections of the chart.

Below is some part from my code please help me identify the possible issue:

```
import { Highcharts,Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';
declare var require: any;
require('highcharts/highcharts-3d')(Highcharts);

const chart = new Chart(<any>{
chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
          enabled: true,
          alpha: 50,
          beta: 0
        },
  },

plotOptions: {
        pie: {        
          depth: 50,
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          showInLegend: true,
          dataLabels: {
            align: 'right',
            color: '#294469',
            shadow: false,
            x: -10,
            enabled: true,
            inside:true,
            formatter: labelFormatterFunction,
            connectorWidth: 1,
          },

        }
}
```

**Reference chart samples**
[image: Reference chart samples]

***highcharts-3d*** version 0.1.7

***highcharts*** version 6.2.0

P.S: Same chart works fine in JSFiddle

Comment: Can you please show me the labelFormatterFunction?

Comment: labelFormatterFunction=function() {return ' <b>  '+ this.point.y.toFixed(precision)+ ' </b>'+suffix};

Comment: Well, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xs6nt4e7/4/ and everything is working fine. Are you using distance property against data labels?

Comment: I have tried playing around with properties, everything works fine in fiddle but the same chart has issue in my app.
And no im not using distance property.

Comment: ok. Then you need to see how you are loading highcharts modules. Are you using webpack or requirejs?  And which modules are you loading for highcharts and in which order you are laoding?

Comment: I'm using require, the highcharts import is mentioned in the code above.

Comment: Do one thing. Paste these cdn's on your page and see it's working or not?
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

Comment: No difference, unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried using the official highcharts-angular wrapper? It can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: I have now found a way to create and resolve this similar scenario in Fiddle, it requires removing "highcharts-3d.src.js" script.
https://forum.highcharts.com/post108815.html#p108815 

But i have removed the highcharts-3d.src.js script for my app and cleaned the nmp cache as well it still doesn't work in my app.

Comment: I have removed "**highcharts-3d.src.js**" from the following paths in my project **1**: node_modules\highcharts\es-modules\masters , **2**: node_modules\highcharts\js, **3**: node_modules\highcharts.